# How to connect changes some field in model to reflect on view?

Tags: backbone.js

How to connect changes some field in model to reflect on view ?
I have model which holds font-weight and I have that model in view, but how to connect changes of **font-weight** filed in model to reflect on **el** from view ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several approachs that can be applied here on depending that how much delicate you want to be.

#### 1. re-render the whole View any time the Model change

```
initialize: function(){
  this.model.on( "change", this.render, this );
}
```

#### 2. be more precise and only re-render what is needed

```
initialize: function(){
  this.model.on( "change:title", this.renderTitle, this );
  this.model.on( "change:body", this.renderBody, this );
  this.model.on( "change:fontWeight", this.renderFontWeight, this );
}
```

This needs the company of minimal render methods that modify the DOM as a surgeon:

```
renderTitle: function(){
  this.$el.find( "h1" ).html( this.model.get( "title" ) );  
},

renderBody: function(){
  this.$el.find( "p" ).html( this.model.get( "body" ) );  
},

renderFontWeight: function(){
  this.$el.find( "p" ).css( "font-weight", this.model.get( "fontWeight" ) );
}
```

#### 3. use subviews for every part of the Model

I'm not offering any example for this approach because the implementation can be more complex. Just think that your actual `View` is instantiating several `SubViews`, one for the `title`, other for the `body`, and so on. Each one with its own `render` and binding the changes in its concrete `Model` attribute and `re-render` when the attribute changes.

You can check [working jsFiddle code for the approachs 1. and 2.](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/n9Hvf/)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var Font = {};

Font.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        font_family: 'Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
        font_size:   12,
        font_weight: 'normal'
    }
});

Font.View = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {

        var this_view = this;

        this.model.bind('change:font_weight', function(model) {

            // Do something with this_view.el
            alert('handle the font-weight change');

        });
    }
});

var myFontModel = new Font.Model();

var myFontView = new Font.View({
    model: myFontModel
});

myFontModel.set({font_weight: 'bold'});
```